# Content of tags is not getting on the same line after certain point & it is getting added to the next line . How to get that content on the same line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am coding HTML & CSS in VS Code IDE. I have installed & enabled the prettier extension for better readability of the code & auto-indentation. but my content of tags is not going beyond that certain point on the screen & it is getting added to the next line whenever I save my code by `Ctrl +S` (example: see the last paragraph tag). How to get that content on the same line?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use Prettier if you don't need this behavior. That's what Prettier does: splits lines that are too long. See here https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html